# EcomDev_PHPUnit assert block property contains

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, ecomdev-phpunit, unit-tests

I am having a problem asserting that a blocks property contains an array key.

I have added a link to the my customer account area using the following XML:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="namespace_ordermigration">
            <name>migration</name>
            <path>migration/order/list/</path>
            <label>Migrated Orders</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

That `addLink` method is called on the block `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` which has a protected property `$_links = array();`

Here the closest I could get with a `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Controller` test:

```
public function testMyAccountButtonDefined()
{
    $this->dispatch('migration/order/list');

    $this->assertLayoutBlockPropertyEquals('customer_account_navigation', '_links', array('migration' => ''));
}
```

Which fails:

```
1) Namespace_OrderMigration_Test_Controller_OrderController::testMyAccountButtonDefined
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
Array (
-    'migration' => ''
+    'migration' => Varien_Object Object (...)
+    'account' => Varien_Object Object (...)
+    'account_edit' => Varien_Object Object (...)
+    'address_book' => Varien_Object Object (...)
...
```

Does anybody know how I could get access to the property it is testing so I could do a simpler PHPUnit test with the results?

Another potential option is creating a new wrapper around the `assertContains` method of `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` in `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Controller` called something like `$this->assertLayoutBlockPropertyContains`. This is quite a bit of work and it would probably be better spent exposing the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended tested a blocks property contains the array key I defined in my layout.xml, a bit more of a direct route and only possible as the property is exposed in the block, so not a valid answer just a work around

```
public function testMyAccountButtonDefined()
{
    $this->dispatch('migration/order/list');

    /* @var $block Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation */
    $block = $this->app()->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');

    $this->assertContains('migration', array_keys($block->getLinks()));
}
```